# How to get the distance from a source to all points within a maximum distance with graph-tool (using Dijkstra algorithm)

Tags: dijkstra, graph-tool

I'm trying to use graph-tool to quickly calculate the distance from a source vertex to all vertices within a maximum distance, using a cost property that I have available for each edge.

I suppose I have to use the `dijkstra_search` function, but how do I specify the stop-criterium ? I have a working example, but I think it traverses the entire graph (taking several seconds as it's the entire road network of Holland).

Second, what's the fastest way of generating a list of: (vertex-id, distance) once the `dijkstra_search` function finishes ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was pretty easy:

```
import graph_tool.all as gt
dm = G.new_vp("double", np.inf)    
gt.shortest_distance(G, source=sourcenode, weights=EdgePropertyMap, dist_map = dm, max_dist=0.1)
```